# How is a schema stored in local cache in Producer(Already registered in Schema Registry)

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

As we know that Producers have a local cached memory where it stores schema(Registered in Schema Registry).
After registering a unique schema an Id is generated.

Does this cache uses this generated Id as a key for the mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Schemas are stored by an MD5 hash of the schema string, and there are three caches

```
private final Map<String, Map<Schema, Integer>> schemaCache;
private final Map<String, Map<Integer, Schema>> idCache;
private final Map<String, Map<Schema, Integer>> versionCache;
```

https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/CachedSchemaRegistryClient.java

If you're asking because you want to access the cache, then you would need to use reflection to access these fields

Comment: If I want to publish a data, which of these mappings are accessed from local cache?
Is the schema is matched and Id is picked to be sent as a part of record?

Comment: Well, you can look at the source code, but I think the schema cache is accessed